# What's the representation of point in time in Perforce

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

A git commit hash represents the project at a specific time, what's the equivalent concept (a "thing" that represent a snapshot of the entire repo at a particular time) in Perforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The submitted changelist number in Perforce serves the same purpose as a commit hash in git in terms of being a version specifier that applies across the entire repository.

Compared to the commit hash, changelist numbers also have the advantage of being comparable (submissions are required to be in order, with changelists being "renumbered" at submit time if necessary to preserve this property).

Date/timestamps can also be used as a revision specifier in most contexts where a changelist number or label can be used.  A timestamp is essentially an alias for the changelist most recently submitted at that point in time.